# Why is my Bootstrap accordion not expanding/collapsing in my Angular app?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5, accordion

I created an Accordion Angular component using Bootstrap. However, the collapsing and expanding is not working. I just copied the bootstrap code into my

**accordion.component.html**

```
<div class="accordion accordion-flush col-md-3" id="accordionFlushExample">
<div class="accordion-item">
  <h2 class="accordion-header">
    <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseOne">
      Accordion Item #1
    </button>
  </h2>
  <div id="flush-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
    <div class="accordion-body">Placeholder content for this accordion, which is intended to demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> class. This is the first item's accordion body.</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion-item">
  <h2 class="accordion-header">
    <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseTwo" disabled>
      Accordion Item #2
    </button>
  </h2>
  <div id="flush-collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
    <div class="accordion-body">Placeholder content for this accordion, which is intended to demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> class. This is the second item's accordion body. Let's imagine this being filled with some actual content.</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion-item">
  <h2 class="accordion-header">
    <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseThree">
      Accordion Item #3
    </button>
  </h2>
  <div id="flush-collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
    <div class="accordion-body">Placeholder content for this accordion, which is intended to demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> class. This is the third item's accordion body. Nothing more exciting happening here in terms of content, but just filling up the space to make it look, at least at first glance, a bit more representative of how this would look in a real-world application.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I inspect the page, I see "[webpack-dev-server] Server started: Hot Module Replacement disabled, Live Reloading enabled, Progress disabled, Overlay enabled." I'm not sure if this is a reason why the collapsing/expanding is not working. If so, how do I resolve this?

I checked the id for each div and ensured that they tallied and they do. I also tested it on a non-Angular html file and it works. However, I'm not sure why my accordion is not working in my Angular app.

Comment: Just to make sure, you did include Bootstrap's javascript files?

Comment: I installed Bootstrap using npm @HansKeﬆing

Comment: Which should mean that the js file is on your disk, but does the HTML page get that? Did you use the correct `<script>` line? See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/introduction/ point 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can add NgBootstrap (https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started) to your Angular application and use the accordion component (https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/overview)